# AlertDialog not working above the QuillTextEditor

Tags: flutter, android-alertdialog

I’m building an AlertDialog for when the user clicks the button but the fields are empty. Right now, the alert is showing, but I cannot interact with the buttons due to the HTML editor. Not sure if it is the QuillEditor.

It only works if I make the page small enough so the button is out of the HTML editor.

The alertDialog has already the safeArea enabled, but whenever I try to click on the button, the HTML editor or the QuillTextEditor activates in the background

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily disable the interactivity of the QuillEditor when the AlertDialog is displayed. You can achieve this by setting a flag and using it to enable/disable the editor.